# Graphql response error. String cannot represent value of JSON

Tags: typescript, graphql, express-graphql

I have an error here at graphql. I'm trying get an airport name through JSON data. I need a single item which's (name of the airport) but I'm receiving array of items with it's city, country, geolocation and so on. Here's the code I'm trying with...

```
const getNameOfAirport = (name:any)=>{
    return AIRPORTS.filter((i)=>{
        if(i.iata_code === name){
            return i.name.length;
        }
    })
}
```

when i run condole.log(getNameOfAirport("BLR")) i'm receiving

```
[
  {
    name: 'Bangalore',
    city: 'Bangalore',
    country: 'India',
    iata_code: 'BLR',
    _geoloc: { lat: 12.949986, lng: 77.668206 },
    links_count: 195,
    objectID: '3131'
  }
]
```

I need a response with

```
Bangalore
```

Any answers much appreciated. Let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Note: I'm using typescript. It works with JSX as i expected. It's going wrong with TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are multiple mistakes

Well you use Typescript, but put `any` for your type. Why do you even use typescript at the first place? But thats a other question
Here:

```
const getNameOfAirport = (name:any)=>{
    return AIRPORTS.filter((i)=>{
        if(i.iata_code === name){
            return i.name.length;
        }
    })
}
```

I see you use `AIRPORTS`, and its an array. But you dont pass it into the function, so the array is outside the function. Sideeffects are bad. You should avoid that.

`Array.filter()` is the wrong method i guess. You should probably try `.find()`

You should also create an interface. Try this:

```
const getNameOfAirport = (
  airports: Airport[],
  name: string
): string | undefined => {
  return airports.find((airport) => airport.iata_code === name)?.name;
};

interface Airport {
  name: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  iata_code: string;
  _geoloc: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };
  links_count: number;
  objectID: string;
}
```

Then you call it with:

```
getNameOfAirport(AIRPORTS, "BLR")
```

A side note: The name `getNameOfAirport` is kinda bad naming. I would suggest to use something like `getAirportNameByIataCode`. By reading the function its pretty clear whats doing.